# Lack of ripples in Bootstrap Material Design

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

I am trying to implement the [bootstrap-material-design](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-material-design/#demo-programmatic-tab) theme to my existing Bootstrap site.

In my `main.blade.php`, I have this on top to denote the stylesheets.

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.2.1/css/material.min.css" />
{{--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/material-fullpalette.min.css" />--}}

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/material.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/ripples.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is in my main blade file - this is the blade wrapper file that exists across *all* my views.

At the bottom of this main blade, I have this JS as instructed by the docs:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.material.init();
    });
</script>
```

However, when I try to click on my button or nav bar elements, there is no ripple effect. I do not see any errors on my console either.

Do I need to add any additional code to my button classes?

EDIT:

Here's the Network tab:

[image]

Comment: can you have any error in console?

Comment: Nope, there are no errors in the conosle

Comment: can you upload it somewhere so i can see

Comment: This is my main [blade](https://github.com/jackyliang/loop.tf/blob/test_material_design/resources/views/app_sched.blade.php), and this is the [libs](https://github.com/jackyliang/loop.tf/blob/test_material_design/resources/views/libs/libs.blade.php)

Comment: Also the pastebin dump of the entire page: http://pastebin.com/gXEa49GH

Comment: i am just run this file but output is like http://prntscr.com/7xv3bi

Comment: Looks like you're missing the CSS for Bootstrap! As you can see from my code, I have a local copy of the CSS `all/css`. You'll need to link in a CDN Bootstrap CSS I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this one. i change order or scripts and add one css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/ripples.min.css">
```

---

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <title></title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/roboto.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/material-fullpalette.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/ripples.min.css">


    <script type="text/javascript"></script>


    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">           
            <button class="btn btn-success ripple-effect">Wow.!</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info ripple-effect">Ripple Work.!</button>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
 <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/ripples.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
    $(function() 
    {
        $.material.init();
    });
});    
</script>
```

Comment: Did you have to manually add the `ripple-effect` class to each button in order for it to work?

Comment: Turns out putting it on the bottom was the trick! Thanks Paresh!

Comment: No need to add. you can remove also. by default it is added to control

Comment: for those using it with angular (in a one page app), don't forget to load arrive.js, it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Load `arrive.js` before the `material-design.js`

Install using bower `bower install arrive --save`